# Hibernate: Saving a link table where one side has a unique constraint

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have the following schema (abbreviated)

```
Comment id, content, createdBy
Attribute id, key, value (unique constraint on key, value)
CommentAttribute id, comment_id, attribute_id
```

So it's a fairly simple schema.

I've mapped it with the simplest entities for the Comment and Attribute entities, so I won't post the code here.

The CommentAttribute is as follows

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "comment_attributes")
public class CommentAttribute {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Cascade(value = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "comment_id", nullable = false)
    private Comment comment;

    @Cascade(value = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "attribute_id", nullable = false)
    private Attribute attribute;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public CommentAttribute setId(final Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public Comment getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public CommentAttribute setComment(final Comment comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
        return this;
    }

    public Attribute getAttribute() {
        return attribute;
    }

    public CommentAttribute setAttribute(final Attribute attribute) {
        this.attribute = attribute;
        return this;
    }
}
```

The intention is that a user will add a comment with one or more attributes. Something like the abbreviated GraphQL below

```
addComment(content: "a comment", [{name: "threadId" value: "thread1"}])
```

I'm using Spring JPA and Hibernate, so I would like to model the above so that it is easy to add records to the link table. I have a test as below:

```
@Test
public void whenAddingTwoCommentsWithSameAttributesThenNoDuplicateCreated() {
    Comment comment = new Comment();
    comment.setCreatedBy("user1");
    comment.setContent("some test comment");

    Attribute attribute = new Attribute();
    attribute.setKey("threadId");
    attribute.setValue("thread1");

    CommentAttribute commentAttribute = new CommentAttribute();
    commentAttribute.setComment(comment);
    commentAttribute.setAttribute(attribute);

    commentAttributeRepository.saveAndFlush(commentAttribute);

    Comment comment2 = new Comment();
    comment2.setCreatedBy("user1");
    comment2.setContent("some test comment2");

    Attribute attribute2 = new Attribute();
    attribute2.setKey("threadId");
    attribute2.setValue("thread1");
    attribute2.setTenantId("customer1");

    CommentAttribute commentAttribute2 = new CommentAttribute();
    commentAttribute2.setComment(comment2);
    commentAttribute2.setAttribute(attribute2);

    commentAttributeRepository.saveAndFlush(commentAttribute2);

    final List<CommentAttribute> all = commentAttributeRepository.findAll();
    assertThat(all).hasSize(2);
    assertThat(all.get(0).getComment().getContent()).isEqualTo("some test comment");
    assertThat(all.get(0).getAttribute().getValue()).isEqualTo("thread1");

    assertThat(all.get(1).getComment().getContent()).isEqualTo("some test comment2");
    assertThat(all.get(1).getAttribute().getValue()).isEqualTo("thread1");

}
```

So the attribute2 variable is actually non-unique. When saving commentAttribute2 I get a unique constraint violation on the attributes table, which is not surprising as Hibernate is trying to insert a new record.

What I would like is for Hibernate to use the existing attribute record if it exists, otherwise create a new record and use that. Is there some way of configuring that with annotations? If not, will I have to look up the attribute entity, and only create a new one if it is not found?

Comment: I don't see how. You have to load the `Comment` and its attributes and see if the attribute you want to add already exists in the attributes set. If so, do nothing, if not, add it. You also need to lookup the `Attribute` first and see if such an attribute already exists. I don't know any place JPA is setup to do all that for you. Also, why do you need an id for the join table? Why not just use a `ManyToMany` annotation on the Comment entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that JPA does the correct thing if fetch the attributes for a comment first and leave it up to the attributes to self-identify. Also, you don't need to manually create a join table, JPA will do that for you as well.

```
@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Attribute> attributes;
    // getters, setters
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Attribute {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    // getters, setters, 
    // AND hashCode and equals using the id field
}
```

Then the second insert does nothing since the Attribute already exists in the set as identified by the `equals` method checking the id. What you have to do is get the set of current attributes along with the existing comment.

```
tx.begin();
Comment c = new Comment();
Attribute a = new Attribute();
em.persist(a);
c.setAttributes(new HashSet<>());
c.getAttributes().add(a);
em.persist(c);
tx.commit();

// to remove everything from cache
em.clear();

// this does nothing except a select since the attribute is already in the set of attributes
// and in fact the `em.find` does not issue a select in this case because
// the attribute gets loaded into the cache from the Comment select.
tx.begin();
Comment c2 = em.createQuery("select c from Comment c left join fetch c.attributes where c.id = 2", Comment.class).getSingleResult();
Attribute a2 = em.find(Attribute.class, 1);
c2.getAttributes().add(a2);
tx.commit();
```

Comment: I prefer to map the join table manually after reading some best practices in that if the join table ever needs any metadata it’s very difficult to change the code to support it. So there is no way apart from selecting from the the database then adding to the new relation? It’s odd that there isn’t a built in hibernate idiom for that.

Comment: Well, I figure why write code now that's not needed, but no matter. Checking if a attribute exists is more application logic so it doesn't make sense to put it into JPA as far as I can tell.

Comment: I restructured the code to lookup/create the attribute before populating the link table, and removed cascading from it. It's not too bad, just a shame I couldn't use the upsert type features that a lot of databases support.